# VBA: Automatically moving charts to individual sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am working on a VBA programm which opens up a selected .csv file, creates charts with the values inside that .csv file and saves it as a new .xlsx file on a selected path.
Creating the graphs and adding titles to them is working fine, but I would like to save each graph (there are 5 graphs created in those .csv files) in a separate new sheet within that file. The Graphs are all created from selected ranges from "Sheet1" and I have created new sheets with:

```
Sheets.Add.Name = "Example1"
Sheets.Add.Name = "Example2"
Sheets.Add.Name = "Example3"
```

Now I dont know how I can move each of those graphs into one of these new sheets.
I thought I might have to give each graph a name with:

```
ActiveChart.Name = "ExampleChart"
```

and then use:

```
Dim ChartObj as Object
ChartObj.ExampleChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, "Example1"
```

To move it there. But that is somehow not working. Thanks for helping

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just create the charts in the sheets in question (`mySht.Shapes.Addchart...` where `mySht` is a worksheet object)

Comment: Otherwise it is a cut/paste operation, not a chart move.  But why add the step when you can add it there.

Comment: If you name a chart ExampleChart that is not the same as creating an object reference called ExampleChart. I think what you meant to do on that line was `Set ExampleChart = ActiveChart`. That way when you're referencing it later to use `ExampleChart.Location`, it will actually reference an object. And `ChartObj` is not needed.

Comment: That or name each of the charts and then reference them using `Charts("Name")`. ChartObj is also not needed in this and your location line would look like `Charts("Name").Location .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to create the chart in the sheet you want to move it to (as mentioned in the comments).
If you want to move the chart from an existing sheet to the created sheet, you can use something like this.

```
Dim chartobj As ChartObject

Set chartobj = Sheets("Sheet3").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=300, Top:=7, Height:=200) 'create chart in original sheet

chartobj.Name = "example chart" 'names chart

Sheets.Add.Name = "Example Sheet" 'creates new sheet

chartobj.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, "Example Sheet" 'moves chart to new sheet
```